# C# Reading a binary text file without knowing the format of the file

Tags: c#, .net, binary, binaryreader

Ok so I have a Binary text file written using a BinaryWriter.
The format of the file has been lost due to poor documentation.

Im using the BinaryReader to read the file but the only way I can do this is through trial and error by stepping through the file and guessing whether I should be using the ReadInt64(), ReadString() etc of the BinaryReader class.

Is there anyway to step through the file and automatically determine what the next value format is?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "binary text file". A file is either binary, meaning that the bytes represent data in some arbitrary (but known) form, or it is a text file, meaning that the bytes encode text characters in one of the known text encodings.

Comment: You might consider opening the file in a binary (hex) file viewer so that you can examine the format. That's going to give you a much better idea of how to read it than using trial and error with `BinaryReader`. Visual Studio will display a binary file.

Answer (score 2):

No. The BinaryWriter does not pack any type information into the written file, so there is no way to reverse-engineering that - other than trial & error, as you have found out.

Comment: Bah that's not what I wanted to hear.